# standardizeing data ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, artificial-intelligence

[here is the error im geting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp868.png)

the exsample im using dataframe only has intgers but the dataframe im using has stings as well as intgers

Answer (score 0):

You cannot standardize non-numerical values. This standardizer accepts string inputs aswell, but tries to convert them to a float before standardization (for example if your DataFrame consisted of strings containing numbers ("2")). In your case string "1 Acorn Place" cannot be converted to a float, because it contains non-numerical characters. If you want to standardize something like strings, you first need to find a suitable embedding for your strings and standardize the embedding vector afterwards.
Although it is relatively advanced you could try and understand this article, which explains a specific embedding approach: https://towardsdatascience.com/sequence-embedding-for-clustering-and-classification-f816a66373fb